# What does "domain or user is in the queue only list. Message queued" mean?

Tags: email, smtp, exim

Emails to my domain are periodically being delayed. I see in Exim's log file `/var/log/exim_mainlog` messages like the following:

```
2013-05-16 18:58:18 1Ud77q-0002ns-Rd <= email@my.host.name U=ssupport P=local S=4350 id=B72DE31368745098-alerts@my.host.name T="Some Subject" for my@email.com
2013-05-16 18:58:18 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1Ud77q-0002ns-Rd
2013-05-16 18:58:18 1Ud77q-0002ns-Rd == my@email.com R=queueonly defer (-1): domain or user is in the queue only list.  Message queued
```

I found in `/etc/exim.conf` the following router configuration:

```
queueonly:
    driver = redirect
    domains = +queue_domains
    condition = ${if eq {$domain}{$primary_hostname}{${if eq {${lookup passwd{$local_part}{$value}}}{}{1}{0}}}{1}}
    allow_defer
    data = :defer: domain or user is in the queue only list.  Message queued
```

That's clearly where the `domain or user is in the queue only list.  Message queued` message originates from. It looks like this will run if the domain is listed in `/etc/queuedomains`

I am not familiar with the file `/etc/queuedomains`. What process manages this file? Is there a setting in Webhost Manager that controls which domains get listed in `/etc/queuedomains`?

How can I prevent the Exim message `domain or user is in the queue only list. Message queued` for my particular domain?

---

**UPDATE:** Upon further investigation, I am getting the message "domain or user is in the queue only list.  Message queued" even when `/etc/queuedomains` is empty. I was watching the exim_mainlog and as soon as I saw "domain or user is in the queue only list.  Message queued" I executed a `cat /etc/queuedomains` in a second terminal and it was 0 bytes. So something else is at play here.

Comment: I am guessing this is due to a new cPanel/WHM feature. I am going to research this further and will answer my own question when/if I find the answer.

Comment: Hmm, It is something new, i've never seen that before. Did it make your sending performance worse? I mean how big the queue gets?

Comment: Sending performance is not dramatically worse that I have noticed. The messages which do get queued show up in the WHM "Mail Queue Manager" but it doesn't appear like other email is affected. Not sure yet though.

Comment: @DanilaLadner It's a confirmed bug, fixed in 11.38.0.10

Comment: Oh, makes sense now. Thanks for follow up, will know now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in cPanel, the use of which is not professional system administration within the scope of the FAQ.

Comment: @FalconMomot unfortunately some professional systems administrators like myself are required to support and maintain cPanel for our customers. cPanel is used in large scale web hosting and **is** on topic. I didn't ask to have to maintain cPanel but it *is* one of my responsibilities as a systems administrator. Questions about cPanel from a *user* perspective are off-topic; questions about cPanel from the *sysadmin* side are on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in cPanel 11.38. I opened a support ticket with cPanel and their response was:

> A new internal case, 68457, was opened by Nick concerning the issue
>   with the queued domain handling for users outside the jail or virtfs
>   environment. A new router is set to be added for handling in that
>   case, which would deliver the message via SMTP rather than using the
>   prior /etc/queuedomains behavior.
>
> When this case has gone into production, it would appear in
>   http://go.cpanel.net/changelog for 11.38 tier. You can see which
>   version is available for each tier at http://httpupdate.cpanel.net
>   location.

Updating to cPanel/WHM 11.38.0 (build 10) resolved this issue.